# Java Basics Help

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am making an android application and i am confused in this section of the code. I am integrating bluetooth and making a call to startApp in the previous class. I want to show these buttons on the main page when startApp is called. From my understanding This is how I would go about doing this? Why Can't I do this? When i try to do this, eclipse doesn't let me. How would i change the code so that i could set up the main menu start page like shown below?

Thanks!!

```
main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="85dip" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView 
            android:text="@string/mainTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
            android:textSize="24.5sp"/>


        <!-- Patient Option -->
        <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/patientButton"
            android:id="@+id/patientButton">
        </Button>

        <!-- Doctor Option -->
        <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/doctorButton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/doctorButton">
        </Button>

        <!-- Exit Mode -->
        <Button android:text="@string/exit" 

         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:id="@+id/exit" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

         <!-- About Mode -->
        <Button android:text="@string/aboutButton" 

         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:id="@+id/aboutButton" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>



    package com.joshi.remotedoc;

import com.joshi.remotedoc.DeviceList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Remote_DocActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {    
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    //private static final String TAG = "Remote_Doc";
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChat";
    private static final boolean D = true;
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
            }        
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");
        // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            } 
        else {
            startApp();
            }
        }

    private void ensureDiscoverable() {
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "ensure discoverable");
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() !=
            BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
            Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
            startActivity(discoverableIntent);
            }
        }
    private void startApp(){

        View Patient_Button = findViewById(R.id.patientButton);
        Patient_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
        Patient_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent b = new Intent(this, Detailed_ModeActivity.class);
                startActivity(b);
                break;
                }
            }
        );
        View Doctor_Button = findViewById(R.id.doctorButton);
        Doctor_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
        View About_Option = findViewById(R.id.aboutButton);
        About_Option.setOnClickListener(this);
        View Exit_Option = findViewById(R.id.exit);
        Exit_Option.setOnClickListener(this);



    }

    /*private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleData(Data data) {

        }
        }*/
    private void connectDevice(Intent data, boolean secure) {
        // Get the device MAC address
        String address = data.getExtras()
        .getString(DeviceList.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
        // Get the BluetoothDevice object
        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        // Attempt to connect to the device
        //mChatService.connect(device, secure);
        }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.patientButton:
            Intent b = new Intent(this, Detailed_ModeActivity.class);
            startActivity(b);
            break;
        case R.id.doctorButton:
            Intent a = new Intent(this, Detailed_ModeActivity.class);
            startActivity(a);
            break;
        case R.id.aboutButton:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.exit:
            finish();
            break;
        }

    }   


}
```

Comment: what does your main activity's layout xml look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Intent b = new Intent(this, Detailed_ModeActivity.class);
```

Try this:

```
Intent b = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Detailed_ModeActivity.class);
```

Comment: The project compiles but i get an error message on my phone saying the app has randomly closed

Comment: So that error is fixed and it compiles, now there's another error. Use your emulator to run the app and when you get the error look at the stack trace. Debugging and tracing errors is a big part of development.

Comment: Now is a good time to learn about [LogCat](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html).

Answer (score 2):

I have a few points that might help:

1. Reading the errors Eclipse give you is a great advantage, many of your problems will be solved just by reading it.
2. Is your `startApp` method in your activity? If not, you cannot call `findViewById` there, because this is a method of `Activity` objects.
3. You have many `.setOnClickListener(this);` in your code, does your class implement `OnClickListener`? it has to be if you want it to be set as the `OnClickListener` of your views

Comment: the full activity class is above

Comment: The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<Detailed_ModeActivity>) is undefined

Comment: Ahh... you need to pass it context.